# Hash::check method doesn't return true on email keys

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array, cakephp-3.0

I have the following array

```
$array = [
    'top' => [
        'under' => [
            'emails' =>
                [
                    'test@email.com' => [
                        'key' => 'value',
                    ],
                    'other' => [
                        'key' => 'value',
                    ]
                ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Then I execute the following command

```
$tmp = Hash::check($array, 'top.under.emails.test@email.com');
```

This returns `false`

If I change the email value to just `test` and then I execute the following line:

```
$tmp = Hash::check($array, 'top.under.emails.test');
```

It returns `true`. So I am guessing this is a problem because of the `@` character... Is there a way to work around this?

Summarizing:

```
$tmp = Hash::check($array, 'top.under.emails.other');
var_dump($tmp); //true
$tmp = Hash::check($array, 'top.under.emails.[test@email.com]');
var_dump($tmp); //false
$tmp = Hash::check($array, 'top.under.emails.test@email.com');
var_dump($tmp); //false
$tmp = Hash::check($array, 'top.under.emails.test@email.com.key');
var_dump($tmp); //false
```

Comment: Dont you need the string indicator i.e. `$tmp = Hash::check($array, '{s}.top.under.emails.test@email.com');`

Comment: No I don't. If I did then this ``$tmp = Hash::check($array, 'top.under.emails.test');`` wouldn't return ``true``.

Comment: Did you try `$tmp = Hash::check($array, 'top.under.emails.test@email.com.key');`?

Comment: First of all what if the key doesn't exist and the email does? I don't want to check if the key exists. I want to check if the email address exists. Anyway it returns ``false``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square brackets around the email key to match the specific key:-

```
Hash::check($array, 'top.under.emails[test@email.com]');
```

Comment: Oh... you are not putting a dot. That's why... let me test it.

Comment: When you use the square bracket notation you don't use the dot as it is equivalent. Glad it's working for you.

Comment: For any future reference I found out that the problem is the ``dot`` and not the ``@`` because there are functions inside the Hash class that use ``explode('.', $data)``